# Using -directwrite in qt under different windows versions

Tags: qt, windows-xp, directwrite

Good day!

I am using Qt 4.8.4, compiled with -directwrite. It requires DWrite.dll which works only under Windows Vista SP2 and upper, and program can't be run under Windows XP.

How can do to fix this problem?

Can I to compile Qt so that it would needed DWrite.dll in Windows 7 and not needed in Windows XP? Are there another ways? Must I to make different distributives for different windows versions or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've compiled with the `directwrite` library it'll be required for the Qt libraries when trying to deploy. You can do platform specific includes and requires in the `.pro` files but you'll need to do some manual changes for that to work.